# "A family in China travelled from Wuhan to the city of Guangzhou."

Tags: articles

> A family in China travelled from Wuhan to **the city of** Guangzhou.

Why is there 'the'? Can we use instead:

> A family in China travelled from Wuhan to a city of Guangzhou.

OR

> A family in China travelled from Wuhan to a city known as Guangzhou.

Comment: I am sorry, I downvoted. This is too basic. Is there universally a city called Guangzhou?

Answer (score 2):

Guangzhou is the name of a city in the province of Guangdong, whereas Wuhan is the name of a city in the province of Hubei.

They may be using "travel to the city of Guangzhou" because they think the reader doesn't know it's a city.

If they said "to a city of Guangzhou", it wouldn't make sense because there is only one such city.

Your last example,"from Wuhan to a city known as Guangzhou" could be used, but it explicitly assumes the reader doesn't know that Guangzhou is a city.

Finally, it might be alright to say "from Wuhan to Guangzhou", if you know the reader will understand that both place-names are cities.